# Use on-screen numpad in Chrome on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, virtual, windows-10

We are using Chrome, on a Windows 10 touch screen machine, to run a web app. Users are using a numeric id and password to login.

By using input type tel/number you can get it to show the non-qwerty keyboard, but it shows a lot of characters that we don't use.

Is there any way to only show a simple keypad?

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to get a numpad only using the Windows on screen keyboard.